# How to host the basic ASP.NET Core 2 WebAPI application on IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an application as in subject, just selecting "ASP.NET Core Web Application", ".NET Core", "ASP.NET Core 2.0", "Web API".

This creates a simple application, where the 'default' call, "api/values", returns the JSON array '["value1", "value2"] (with only a minor warning on the browser).

So far so good.

Now I would like to deploy this application on an IIS, just using the FolderProfile, so I build the application, I publish it, and I have this directory with all the files needed to run it. I see that a web.config is added (it is not in the sources), with the correct configuration to start the runtime with the generated dll.

I copy this directory on a physical directory, I create a web site within an application pool, in short, everything, and I configure it as common sense suggests, since I couldn't find any tutorial for ASP.NET Core 2. The docs for Core 1 don't apply correctly, since there are many changes...

In the end I always end up with this result:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

The generated web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Core2WebService.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 5c8e6f19-9a61-47c5-8ee1-8c4b54962ba2-->
```

I tried whatever I could, but always with this end result... Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: ...obviously I installed the ASP.NET Core 2 SDK on the target machine...

Comment: check [Host on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) documentation. Right now it looks like you at least forgot to Install the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore.2.0.0-windowshosting)

Comment: .NET Core Server Hosting??? Where could I find this information? I installed 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0-win-gs-x64': I will give a try...

Comment: my last comment contains links

Comment: Hey man, you just saved my day! Thank you really a lot! And how can I give you credit? I think you have to post a proper answer, instead of a comment.

Comment: cool, happy to help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Host on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) documentation. Right now it looks like you at least forgot to Install [the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#install-the-net-core-windows-server-hosting-bundle).

The bundle will install the ASP.NET Core Module in addition that creates the reverse-proxy between IIS and the Kestrel server.

Comment: Thank you. It saves me a lot of time. Installing the hosting bundle is the critical step.

Comment: Please check the link, it is broken

Answer (score 0):

You can directly publish from your .Net Core application.

I have written a step by step guide for the same, only difference is, I have explained to host the application instead of Web API.

Have a look here: https://neelbhatt.com/2018/01/30/deploy-net-core-application-to-iis-step-by-step-guide/